# How to enable snapping animation keys in the «Graph Editor»

Tags: graph-editor

How to enable snapping animation keys in the *Graph Editor*, in which after use `Shift` + `D` I could move the selected keys. Key X = 0, Y = 0 exactly snap to animation key X = 20, Y = 2. And then use `Shift` + `R` to duplicate the sawtooth curve? So that after the selected key is moved, it snaps to the neighboring key on the X-axis and Y-axis.

Or it can be done only by knowing the exact coordinates of the key X = 20, Y = 2, calculate the exact offset. And after use `Shift` + `D` write the coordinates of the displacement along X and Y. And then use `Shift` + `R` to duplicate the sawtooth curve?

Maybe there are still alternative ways to make a sawtooth curve?

We do not use the *Cycles* modifier for a curve with «Repeat with Offset» and an indication of *Restrict Frame Range End*, because after the sawtooth curve, if you add new animation keys, then the shape of the initial curve changes. And the new curve repeats cyclically. But on the *Influence* parameter cannot be installed by the driver, and the animation keys cannot be installed.
[image]
Advantage / application snapping animation keys:

1. Replacement / alternative of the Cycles modifier in the "Graph Editor". Manually duplicate animation key loops via `Shift` + `R` with exact binding of the start animation keys to the end animation keys of adjacent loops. Because in the *Cycles* modifier there is no way to put the driver or animation key on the *Influence* parameter. And if you put animation keys on the curve after the end of the *Cycles* modifier, the shape of the curve changes and another shape of the curve is cyclically repeated.

Comment: Did you try holding Ctrl Key while moving?

Comment: Ctrl does not give the desired result. Because it not snapped the active animation key to another animation key.
The analog of snapped active vertex to any other vertex. I want the same thing with the animation keys in the Graph Editor.
https://i.ibb.co/wzwQjkK/snapping-keys.gif